# QT: files being stored in a folder called VirtualStore under appdata

Tags: c++, qt, inno-setup

My application is generating thumbnails and also a sqlite database.

After making an inno setup installer and installing the app for the first time I've found that my files are being created not in the program's directory but under a directory called VirtualStore.

Is this desirable? Is there a way to disable this?

The problem I'm facing is that after I uninstall the program the files are still in that subfolder of VirtualStore... also, I'm not sure this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: In which folder do you create the files?

Comment: what os are you running? and please post the section of inno setup script dealing with these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear as to whether it is asking how to move the files into your `{app}` directory or whether the problem is a actually that because the files are created outside the installer and, therefore, not removed automatically when uninstalled?

I will answer the second part of this, on the assumption that you simply want the files to be removed when uninstalled, as whether they are created in the VirtualStore folder, or your own `{app}` directory, they will still not be removed when the application is uninstalled. This is because the uninstaller, which is created automatically at installation time, is not aware of these files existing. To resolve this, simply add the following section and line to your script:

```
[UninstallDelete]
;Define files and folders that were not created by the installer to be deleted on uninstall
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\VirtualStore"
```

If the location I have interpreted from your question is incorrect, simply modify the path. You can add multiple entries to this section to take care of removing files not installed originally, but created after installation. Refer to the documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm facing is that after I uninstall the program the files
>   are still in that subfolder

InnoSetup doesn't delete the files created by the application after the installation on uninstall by default. It tracks the files it created and uninstalls only those.

However, this seems to be not a Qt question.

Comment: Yes, it is, I don't want the program to use that directory I want the files to be in my app folder.